# uWSGI configuration for Apache for Galaxy instance

Tags: python, linux, apache, centos, uwsgi

I want to setup a Galaxy instance in my server running on CentOS and I have an issue with configuring my Apache server with uWSGI. I have installed uwsgi with pip:

```
pip install uwsgi
```

and added in my Apache configuration file the following lines:

```
<Location "/galaxy">
Sethandler uwsgi-handler
uWSGISocket 127.0.0.1:4001
uWSGImaxVars 512
</Location>
```

as instructed by the Galaxy team. Nevertheless when I restart my web server I get the following error:

```
Invalid command 'uWSGISocket', perhaps misspelled or defined by a mod
```

and it fails to start again.

I'm very new to using Apache for proxying requests so I need any help I can get.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you using to integrate Apache with uWSGI? The [docs](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Apache.html) mention three Apache modules, which one have you installed?

Comment: I've installed mod_wsgi. But now that I look at the docs it's mentionned as mod_uwsgi (which i now tried to install and there in no such package). I'm fairly new to this.. I also looked at my /path/to/httpd/modules/ directory and there is a mod_wsgi.so module there. I don't know if that helps.

Comment: mod_wsgi is completely different from mod_uwsgi; it is an alternative to uWSGI itself. You should install one of the packages from that page, presumably mod_proxy_uwsgi. You should explain what you did to get "no such package"; those definitely exist.

Comment: Only tried the easy way with yum and pip. Didn't download any source code. I'm gonna do just that.

Comment: So I installed the mod_proxy_uwsgi module: `apxs -i -c mod_proxy_uwsgi.c` and added a new line in my Apache configuration file: `LoadModule proxy_uwsgi_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_uwsgi.so` but when i restart the server i get the same error. Any advice?

Comment: You don't use uWSGISocket with that module, you use ProxyPass; again, see [the documentation](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Apache.html#mod-proxy-uwsgi).

Comment: Yeah my bad thanks for the help. I got it right this time by adding the mod_uwsgi module.